# Return array from a function not working

Tags: c#

why my code is not working. I am a beginner, please help. How to return array from a function? Its returning System.Int32[].

```
 namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program a = new Program();
            int[] arr= a.make();
            Console.WriteLine(arr);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public int[] make()
        {
            int[] array = new int[]{9,11,15, 19, 29, 55};

            return array;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Hot tip to a beginnner: Never write 'not working'. Write down why it's not working. Throws an error? post it! Doesn't return what you expect. Explain it! Writing 'not working' means you haven't undertaken basic troubleshooting

Comment: You don't need to instantiate your `Program` class you can just use `make()` without `.` operator

Answer (score 2):

When you do something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(arr);
```

It will output the `ToString()` of that item.

The default implementation is the `Type` of the item.

Since you are using an array, the output will be:

```
System.Int32[]
```

If you want to print out the content, you would like to iterate the array and print:

```
foreach(var item in arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I Assume you want to print the elements in the array,

**Problem:**
When you put a console.WriteLine() the output will be

```
System.Int32[]
```

Because it is an array.

**Solution:**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program a = new Program();
        int[] arr = a.make();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, arr));     
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: How about `String.Join(Environment.NewLine, arr)`? :)

Comment: @Alegnem Yes , that would be better